# Spring 3 JMS on Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jms

Is it possible to implement JMS messaging in tomcat? I have a spring mvc application and I need to implement JMS messaging.

I can not use glassfish. I know its very easy to do JMS messaging with message driven bean but on application server.

So if there is a possibility, can someone provide some examples how to create a JMS connection factory and queue for spring application?

I have a JMS queue sender class:

```
public class JmsQueueSender {

    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    private Queue queue;

    public void setConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactory cf) { //?????????????????????
        this.jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(cf);
    }

    public void setQueue(Queue queue) { //?????????????????????
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void sendMessage(final Serializable object) {
        jmsTemplate.send(this.queue, new MessageCreator() {
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                return session.createObjectMessage(object);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

The main question is how to create a connection factory and queue, what objects to use. In glassfish I have been creating a JMS resource through application server admin console. How can I do this in spring application which runs in tomcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Have you looked at [the JMS chapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-connections) of the Spring manual?

Comment: Yes I have, but there is anything said about how to create connection factory and queue.

Comment: as mentioned in the docs, Spring provides two `ConnectionFactory` implementations for you, `SingleConnectionFactory` and `CachingConnectionFactory`. Depending on what type of message broker you use, they might supply a client library with a `ConnectionFactory` you can use as well (ActiveMQ does this).

Comment: I am trying ActiveMQ now. It seems working, but I am trying to understand it now. Anyway, thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at [Apache TomEE Plus](http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html) which is Tomcat + JMS and more.  You can either drop that into Tomcat via the war distro or get the pre-bundled version.